# CreateProcess works on some computers, not on others. Why?

Tags: c++, windows-7, intel, access-denied, createprocess

I work on an app that calls another app via CreateProcess. I'm on Win7 64 bits. The called app is a console that receive data through a pipe. The calling code looks like this:

```
STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
GetStartupInfoA(&si);
memset( &si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA) );
memset( &pi, 0, sizeof(pi) );
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
char cmdline[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(cmdline,"\"%s\" %s",AppToCallName,PipeName);
BOOL bRet = CreateProcessA(NULL,cmdline,NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE|CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);
```

On my computers (I tried on two), it works. On other ones, it returns (bRet=)FALSE then GetLastError() returns 5 which means ACCESS_DENIED.

I cannot figure out where is the problem. And the bad thing is that it works for me so I can't debug it!

My setup is:

- Win7 Pro 64 bits SP1
- VStudio 2005 SP1
- (Compiler used: Intel C++ 9.1

I will be glad to furnish more setup info if you need it!

Any idea?

Comment: What type of applications are triggering the ACCESS_DENIED? What's on the command line in those situations? Also, do you run your code as an elevated user? I would recommend against it because you won't find this bugs yourself if you do...

Comment: The app that triggers the ACCESS_DENIED is a simple console app that will (would) receive data from the calling app via a named pipe. The pipe creation is correct. The command lines look like this: "\"MyConsoleApp.exe\" ThePipeName" Both the caller and the called apps are located in the same directory.

Comment: Also, we all have admin privileges here. Even those who can't run my app on there computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateProcess` uses the same permissions as the calling process it also will terminate the process if it has not initialized properly so you should wait and verify the process launched even if `CreateProcess` returns success. However your access denied issue is probably related to your calling process not having execute or write permissions on whatever application you were attempting to launch on the target machine.

In addition to `GetLastError` when the function succeeds check `GetExitCodeProcess` as that will probably be your next problem.

Also for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. More info: on my computer, it succeed when I run it from my HD but it fails when I run it from a USB key. Timing????

Comment: How does CreateProcess work internally? Does it start the process asynchronously then returns? If so, how does it know if it succeeded or failed? On the other hand, if the process is created synchronously, how could be a timing problem? The second app will run at the same speed what ever it is loaded from the HD or from the USB key... I'm mystified!

Comment: "it also will terminate the process if it has not initialized by the time the function returns" that's not really an exact quote. MSDN says CreateProcess returns before initialization finished, so even with a successful CreateProcess the process may still terminate because initialization failed.

Comment: @dom When you run the app from USB the system may well copy it locally first; that may be what is failing. Try filemon - that may well show what is failing.

Comment: @dom_beau, use WaitForSingleObject with the process handle to wait for the process to terminate. Then use GetExitCodeProcess to check the exit code.

Comment: @dom_beau I probably wouldn't run any application from USB directly. Also pezcode I wasn't quoting anything but that is correct I'll reword it to not be misleading.

Comment: I don't know what to think about it... I ran it: it didn't work. I installed procmon (replaces filemon) then ran it. Now my app works. I can't figure how to make it bug again! And it is from my USB key in both cases. I'm sure there is a timing issue somewhere but I can't figure where.

Comment: I put the code on a shared folder on my colleague's computer. I ran it via the network and it worked. He ran it locally (same code!) and it didn't work: ACCESS_DENIED. He's on Win7/64 pro sp1 too. A good hand clap to the one who can solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled perhaps? Environment issues of this kind are very difficult to solve third hand as there can be many factors that are unknown.

Comment: My UAC is set at max level (always). It still works. The UAC of my colleague is at the second level (from the bottom) and it doesn't work. You're right about the difficulty to solve by third hand, it seems to be impossible to solve by my own hands!

Comment: **Remember**: I use Intel C++ compiler 9.1, not the MS C++ compiler that comes with VS2005... Can this be the source of the problem?

Comment: No. `CreateProcess` is a windows API function located in Kernal32.dll so as long as you `#include <windows.h>` and link Kernel32.lib it really doesn't matter what compiler you use.

Comment: I see now that my computer (where the bug never occurs) has Win7 SP1 while the computers where the bug occurs (sometimes or every time) **don't have SP1**. Can it explain the problem?

Comment: You won't believe me! Other people use **Windows Explorer** while I use **CubicExplorer** (see [this link](http://www.cubicreality.com/ce/)). I tried to run the app from **Windows Explorer** and CreateProcess failed. I tried to launch the _same code_ from **CubicExplorer** and it worked... Do you know what CubicExplorer does that Windows Explorer doesn't or vice versa?????????????????? Note that it works too when launched from Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: I'm sorry but this has been thoroughly derailed from the original topic. Please ask additional questions related to Windows environment, third party open source projects, etc and link this post as a reference.